# change String siteUrl = "file:///android_asset/one.html"; path with click on buttons?

Tags: android, android-studio

i have a webview in Activity_main.xml with id "myweb".
and 3 buttons, btn1 , btn2, btn3.
there are 3 html files in asset folder.
also a main.java file that contain:

```
package mohammadsajadi.lifelinux;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class one extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        String siteUrl = "file:///android_asset/one.html";
        mWebView.loadUrl(siteUrl);
    }
}
```

i want change the path to String siteUrl = "file:///android_asset/two.html"; when i click on btn2 . also for btn3 change path to String siteUrl = "file:///android_asset/three.html"; 
Notice that there is a file for webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use     OnClickListener() and handle the event like this

```
this.button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/one.html");
            }
    });
```

And the same for button2 and button3 but just change the url